# Return and break in foreach-loop ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I try execute this function.

```
  private ArrayList<Note> notes;

  //Adding notes in arraylist

    public Note getNoteByDay(Calendar calendar) {
            for (Note note : notes) {
                if (note.getReminder().getTime() / Constants.DAY_IN_MILLIS == calendar.getTimeInMillis() / Constants.DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
                    Log.d("NOTE_ID", note.getName());
                    return note;
                }
            }
            return null;
    }
```

But when I call this function for different calendar

1. I always get first note.
2. I always get 2 calls of `Log.d()`.
3. When I use `break;` instead `return note;` I always get 1 call of `Log.d()`

Where is my problem?

Comment: Is this the only place you call `Log.d()`?

Comment: Check the size using `notes.size()`

Comment: @VinayakPingale In this particular case, size does not matter.

Comment: Can you share Note implamantation?

Comment: another thing: you can calc `calendar.getTimeInMillis() / Constants.DAY_IN_MILLIS` before you start the loop.

Comment: Possibly there is another Log.d outside of this function. Secondly you do understand this function will always return only one Note or null, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I always get first note.

That's because your first note does fulfill your requirements in if statement.

> 2) I always get 2 calls of Log.d().

It means that issue is not in this code but in place which calls this method. Use debugger or stacktrace to determine who and when calls this method. It also could be multithread or multiclick - whatever environment or platform your are using.

> 3) When I use break; instead return note; I always get 1 call of
>   Log.d() Where is my problem?

That only confirms case 2. On break it returns null and your calling place has null pointer exception and does not call again.

Bottom line - issue is not in this provided code but in place where this method is called. Eclipse has nice feature - it shows where method is used - use this feature.